# Ruby why is my object saving without an ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I feel like I'm missing something very basic, and someone can look at this and very quickly telling me what that is...

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by_id(create_params[:user_id])
    @plan = @user.plans.new(create_params)
    if @plan.save 
      puts @plan.inspect
    end
end
```

Right now the `puts` statement returns this:

```
#<Plan id: nil, zipcode: "02114", selected_plan: 5, user_id: 1>
```

So basically.. all the attributes are there, but there's no id...

More info:

```
create_params = {zipcode:"02114", selected_plan:"5", user_id: 1}
```

And if it's helpful to know, `save!` does work and successfully saves the plan with an id... and `plan.save == true` returns `true`

Comment: What's the value of `create_params`?

Comment: doesn't `save!` update the instance variable, and `save` leave it alone, yet apply the change to the database?

Comment: @vgoff no the `save!` raises an error if validation fails where `save` does not. That should be the only difference between the two IIRC. Could be wrong, of course.

Comment: I knew that it did not make sense to see the user_id in the current code, but wasn't sure if it modified in place.  Ruby usually reserves the '!' to indicate modified in place (dangerous) objects. So that was my initial thought.  But yes, I knew that.  Doh! :)

Comment: That seems weird. Can you reproduce this in a fresh rails app?

Comment: Very weird! I can't reproduce it... but it's also not like I can just build a fresh app and copy everything over...

Comment: Your object is saving with an id, if that object is a reference to the database. That is the job of save but it doesn't make sense that it would know what that user id is until it retrieves it from the database.  (My answer probably should have been a comment.  Sorry about that.)

Comment: What type of database are you using? If you use a database tool to look at the plans table directly, do you see a number of records with an empty id column?

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS. OK I feel very dumb for this. 1) This question was asked poorly, should have specified I was asking in the context of a test. 2) I discovered that way up high in a before statement, I had stubbed the save -_-;;

Answer (score 0):

Your code should have the following pattern.

```
    @user = User.find(create_params[:user_id]) # see changes
    @plan = @user.plans.new(create_params)
    if @plan.save 
      puts @plan.reload.inspect  #reload object to see if the object has been saved!
    else
      puts @plan.errors.messages.inspect  # if object is not saved there should be Object#errors.messages should have messages
    end
```

Comment: @plan.reload throws an error Couldn't find Plan without an ID, so it has not been saved...